# JS script to test a quadrilateral property and output the determined shape?

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started my coding journey and was hoping to get some help.
I have been asked to create a script that receives the length of each side and the angles of each corner from a user (these can be 'hard coded') and determines whether the shape is a square, rectangle, rhombus or a parrelellogram.

I am stuck with the logic while making use of conditional statements and I cannot get past the proof of a rhombus. I do not know if I can use a switch statement - I am not confident that I understand its use.

Please help :D

```js
//Create a program that receives the length of each side and the angles of each corner (these can be hard-coded) and 
//determines whether the shape is a square, a rectangle, a rhombus or a parallelogram.

console.log('Good day! Time to see what shape you are dealing with today.')

sideLength_one = prompt("What is the length of the first side? ");
sideLength_two = prompt("What is the length of the second side?");
sideLength_three = prompt("What is the length of the third side?");
sideLength_four = prompt("What is the length of the fourth side?");

console.log("Awesome! Now let's move to the angles.");

angle_one = prompt("What is the measurement of angle one?");
angle_two = prompt("What is the measurement of angle two?");
angle_three = prompt("what is the measurement of angle three?");
angle_four = prompt("What is the measurement of angle four?");


//test the quadrilateral
if (sideLength_one && sideLength_two && sideLength_three == sideLength_four){
    console.log("Your shape is square!");
}

else if (sideLength_one ==sideLength_three || sideLength_two == sideLength_four){
    console.log("Your shape is a rectangle!");
}

else if ((angle_one < 90 || angle_two < 90) && (sideLength_one && sideLength_two == sideLength_three)){
    console.log ("Your shape is a rhombus!");
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use switch with statements.
I consider that to be abusing a side effect
`switch (true) { case statement1 .... }`

Instead you need to add more &&s

```
if (sideLength_one == sideLength_four && sideLength_two == sideLength_four && sideLength_three == sideLength_four)
```

instead of

```
if (sideLength_one && sideLength_two && sideLength_three == sideLength_four)
```

```js
//Create a program that receives the length of each side and the angles of each corner (these can be hard-coded) and 
//determines whether the shape is a square, a rectangle, a rhombus or a parallelogram.

console.log('Good day! Time to see what shape you are dealing with today.')

sideLength_one = prompt("What is the length of the first side? ");
sideLength_two = prompt("What is the length of the second side?");
sideLength_three = prompt("What is the length of the third side?");
sideLength_four = prompt("What is the length of the fourth side?");

console.log("Awesome! Now let's move to the angles.");

angle_one = prompt("What is the measurement of angle one?");
angle_two = prompt("What is the measurement of angle two?");
angle_three = prompt("what is the measurement of angle three?");
angle_four = prompt("What is the measurement of angle four?");


//test the quadrilateral
if (sideLength_one == sideLength_four && sideLength_two == sideLength_four && sideLength_three == sideLength_four) {
  console.log("Your shape is square!");
} else if (sideLength_one == sideLength_three || sideLength_two == sideLength_four) {
  console.log("Your shape is a rectangle!");
} else if ((angle_one < 90 || angle_two < 90) && (sideLength_one == sideLength_three && sideLength_two == sideLength_three)) {
  console.log("Your shape is a rhombus!");
} else console.log("Your shape is weird!");
```